# Store data from API call as JSON and pass on to ios app

Tags: java, json, api, twitter

I am trying to store data, a collection of tweets, I receive from the Twitter API as JSON data. I have set up a local tomcat server and I am running a REST service on it, this is what makes the call to the API. At present I am storing the data in a Java.util list<>.

This is the code I'm using to store it. It stores the result in a List and then passes it back to another method which send it on to an ios app.

I am a bit unsure of how to this without using the List<>, although I think there should be a way to keep the data in JSON format and send it back to the ios app, which is expecting JSON. I'm just looking for some ideas on how best to this.

```
   List<Status> tweets = null;

        try {
            Query query = new Query("#billmurray");
            QueryResult result;
            result = twitter.search(query);
            tweets = result.getTweets();

            for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText() + " - " + tweet.getGeoLocation());
            }
        }
        catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
      }
        return tweets;
```

Comment: JSON is a form of character string (probably either String or `byte[]` in Java), conceptually similar to XML in some ways.  If you are indeed "passing on" the JSON there is no need to convert ("deserialize") it out of that character string form into the Maps and Lists that represent JSON in Java.  Though you can certainly store a group of such JSON strings in a Map or List independent of whether they've been "deserialized" or not.  (In the above code it's not apparent where any actual JSON data might be.)

Comment: (And don't worry about the iOS side -- iOS speaks JSON far more naturally than does Java.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for helping. In the code I believe the JSON is in the QueryResult, as the Twitter API sends data back as JSON. Then again I could be wrong, I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: Well, most likely the JSON in the QueryResult is still in string form and can be forwarded on without having to "open" it at all, assuming you don't need to modify it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has builtin handling of JSONData you can use something like this:

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];
```

Alternatively you can save the data into an NSDictionary as well if needed.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful for the ios side of things.